# Nginx location without an associated file

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to give Nginx a path that if accessed by a user returns a string without an associated file? At present when I run the following in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-name I just get a 404 when I think I should get the json string returned.

```
location /.well-known/matrix/server {
      default_type application/json;
      return 200 '{"m.server": "example.com:443"}';
      add_header Content-Type application/json;
    }
```

So the goal is for when `example.com/.well-known/matrix/server` is accessed `{"m.server": "example.com:443"}` will be returned. There currently is no associated file at `/var/www/html/.well-known/matrix/server`. I was hoping the return statement in the config file would be all that was needed.

This is the first location block but I can provide the whole file if you think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exact matching instead of by prefix, like so:

```
location = /.well-known/matrix/server {
```

Comment: I actually tried this but it didn’t resolve the issue. The result was the same.